# Why is data missing when processing large MongoDB collections in PyMongo? What can I do about it?

Tags: python, mongodb, collections, pymongo, large-data

I'm having some issues working with a very large MongoDB collection (19 million documents).

When I simply iterate over the collection, as below, PyMongo seems to give up after 10,593,454 documents. This seems to be the same even if I use skip(), the latter half of the collection seems programmatically inaccessible.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client['mydb']
classification_collection = db["my_classifications"]

print "Collection contains %s documents." % db.command("collstats", "my_classifications")["count"]

for ii, classification in enumerate(classification_collection.find(no_cursor_timeout=True)):
  print "%s: created at %s" % (ii,classification["created_at"])

print "Done."
```

The script reports initially:

```
Collection contains 19036976 documents.
```

Eventually, the script completes, I get no errors, and I do get the "Done." message. But the last row printed is

```
10593454: created at 2013-12-12 02:17:35
```

All my records logged in just over the last 2 years, the most recent ones, seem inaccessible. Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? What can I do about this?

Comment: how long is it tunning for before it "ends". Could it be timing out?

Comment: @Takarii as you can see, I have disabled timeouts using `no_cursor_timeout=True`. Having said that, it does hang for ages on that 10,593,454th record. So it does feel like a timeout of sorts. even though the program eventually continues.

But why would it timeout after the same specific record every time?

Comment: Not too sure. Can you query the database directly to see if you can actually retrieve the records in the first place?

Comment: Well MongoHub doesn't seem to allow `.skip()` values greater than `9999` so I am not sure how I could do this.

Comment: Im refering to direct access to the database such that you can do a query where id > xxx

Comment: not sure how I'd find the ID value to query. When I get results back, they don't seem to have sequential IDs.

Comment: put an index on `created_at`, do a projection that returns only that field, since that is all you are printing out (`{_id : 0, created_at : 1}`) and then try this again.  Looks like you are doing a table scan and pulling all fields in each document to print out just one, which is not going to be very efficient and is going to cause a lot of paging from disk - if the database ends up struggling you can hit a timeout elsewhere besides the cursor (network timeout, socket timeout) and you just end up with lots of orphaned immortal cursors on your DB (only way to clean them up is a restart)

Answer (score 1):

OK well thanks to [this helpful article](https://scalegrid.io/blog/fast-paging-with-mongodb/) I found another way to page through the documents, which doesn't seem to be subject to this "missing data"/"timeout" issue. Essentially, you have to use `find()` and `limit()` and rely on the natural `_id` ordering of your collection to retrieve the document in pages. Here's my revised code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client['mydb']
classification_collection = db["my_classifications"]

print "Collection contains %s documents." % db.command("collstats", "my_classifications")["count"]

# get first ID
pageSize = 100000
first_classification = classification_collection.find_one()
completed_page_rows=1
last_id = first_classification["_id"]

# get the next page of documents (read-ahead programming style)
next_results = classification_collection.find({"_id":{"$gt":last_id}},{"created_at":1},no_cursor_timeout=True).limit(pageSize)

# keep getting pages until there are no more
while next_results.count()>0:
  for ii, classification in enumerate(next_results):
    completed_page_rows+=1
    if completed_page_rows % pageSize == 0:
      print "%s (id = %s): created at %s" % (completed_page_rows,classification["_id"],classification["created_at"])
    last_id = classification["_id"]
  next_results = classification_collection.find({"_id":{"$gt":last_id}},{"created_at":1},no_cursor_timeout=True).limit(pageSize)

print "\nDone.\n"
```

I hope that by writing up this solution this will help others who hit this issue.

Note: This updated listing also takes on the suggestions of @Takarii and @adam-comerford in the comments, I now retrieve only the fields I need (`_id` comes by default), and I also print out the IDs for reference.